# VSC Debugger throwing SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Prior to some recent update of Visual Studio Code I was able to debug my Node.js Apps written in TypeScript with this `launch.json` configuration

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug API",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api/src/main.ts",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/apps/api/main.js"],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

But now I'm getting this error

```
import * as express from 'express';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Process exited with code 1
```

Any idea of how can I fix this? Or at least make it work while VSC Team provides an answer on their GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102834

Comment: Exactly my problem at the moment, I can run the app with simple command `npx ts-node src/` but it gives this error when I am running in vscode launch. any update here?

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following:

1. Add (if not already exist) a build step in the `package.json`, something like this;

   ```json
   "ci-build": "npx tsc",
   ```
2. I have in the `tsconfig.json` the following options;

   ```json
   "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "dist",
       "rootDir": "src",
       "module": "commonjs"
       "sourceMap": true,
       "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
       "strict": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "target": "es2017"
   }
   ```

   **Note**: Make sure to set the `sourceMap` to `true`
3. My `launch.json` looks like this;

   ```json
   {
       "type": "node",
       "request": "launch",
       "name": "Build Project",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
       "preLaunchTask": "npm: ci-build",
       "sourceMaps": true,
       "smartStep": true,
       "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
       "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
   }
   ```

For further reading, see [my blog post on the topic](https://pkief.medium.com/how-to-debug-typescript-with-vs-code-9cec93b4ae56)

Comment: Most important for me was setting `sourceMap: true` in `tsconfig.json`, great!

Comment: Setting sourceMap: true worked for me. I missed this one to set. Thanks a lot for the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [a comment on this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102873#issuecomment-674999289), VSC Team has provided a fix for version 1.48 of Visual Studio Code:

```json
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug launcher",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/launcher/src/main.ts",
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Comment: The 'program' field is important in this post. I had 'args' and changed it to 'program' and worked. Note that, 'args' is an array of strings and you should change it to just a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "runtimeArgs" attribute to your launch.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\server.ts",
        "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I hope something in all of this helps you, because it helped me.